# Failed to scan content of a text file

Tags: dart

I am trying to port some java file io code to dart but fails to get any input to be read.

Neither of my listen, onDone or onError methods seems to gets called!

```dart
  static void dumpFile(String filename) {
    print("Dumping: $filename Exists: ${new File(filename).existsSync()} Length: ${new File(filename).lengthSync()}");
    Stream stream = new File(filename).openRead();
    stream
      .listen(
        (List<int> codes) {
         print("CODES: $codes");
        },
        onDone: () {print("Done with file");},
        onError: (e) {print(e.toString());}
      );
    print("Dumping done!");
  }
```

Console output:

```
Dumping: /Users/gunnar/git/chessbuddy/src/test/resources/pgn/testgame13.pgn
Exists: true Length: 565
Dumping done!
```

€ dart --version
Dart VM version: **0.4.7.1_r21537 (Tue Apr 16 01:34:53 2013)**

Comment: What actually happen was that the program stopped due to errors that occurred in the main thread. My bad!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a decoder, and if needed a transformer. Check the Dart Library Tour ([files and directories](http://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/contents/ch03.html#ch03-files-and-directories)) for more information. I guess this is only if you need a readable content for further use.

and maybe this will help:

```dart
static void dumpFile(String filename) {
    print("Dumping: $filename Exists: ${new File(filename).existsSync()} Length: ${new File(filename).lengthSync()}");
    Stream stream = new File(filename).openRead();
    stream
      .transform(new StringDecoder())
      .transform(new LineTransformer())
      .listen(
        (String codes) { //cast to String
         print("CODES: $codes");
        },
        onDone: () {print("Done with file");},
        onError: (e) {print(e.toString());}
      );
    print("Dumping done!");
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

With *Dart Editor version 0.5.0-r21823* your code works and the following output is displayed :

```
Dumping: test/test.dart Exists: true Length: 519
Dumping done!
CODES: [...]
Done with file
```

Note that *Dumping done!* is displayed before *CODES: [...]* because [File.openRead](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_io/File.html#openRead) is an asynchronous operation. You can use [File.readAsBytesSync](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_io/File.html#readAsBytesSync) if you want a synchronous equivalent.